# Accessing a variable on another file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seeding

I have the following seed file that creates specific types of animals that need to be tested:

animal_seeder.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

animal1 = create(:animal, name:"id0_12", type:"fish,  score: 2 ...)
animal2 = create(:animal, name:"id0_123",type:"dog",  score: 121 ...)
animal3 = create(:animal, name:"id0_997",type:"cat",  score: 5 ...)
```

The problem I'm running into right now is that I have 2 others seeders called store_seeder.rb and food seeder that relies on using the animal variables created in the animal_seeder.

eg.

```
create(
  :animal_store,
  timestamp: DateTime.now,
  version: 3,
  targets: {
    "food": {
      food.id=>{
        "animals": {  
            animal1.id =>{
              score:1231, 
              present: true, 
              .....
     }
```

We are looking to test specific use cases so I can't randomly create the variables for the animal variable. Is there a way I can create the animals and use them as a reference across other seeds?

Comment: Is this with FactoryBot? And which test framework?

Comment: @Schwern yup i'm using factory bot

Comment: The structure of animal_store is a bit funny. Is it really a food store and foods are for certain animals?

Comment: @Schwern yeah it's prob not the best example though i'm wondering if conceptually i can do this as we have other instances of our seeds requiring specifically made variables to test data

Answer (score 2):

First, get rid of fixtures. As you're discovering, they're hard to maintain.

Instead, create the animals as needed for your particular tests and pass them to the store.

```
let(:animals) {
  create_list(:animal, 3)
}
let(:animal_store) {
  create(:animal_store, animals: animals)
}
```

Now you know that `animal_store` contains `animals`.

Adding those specific animals to the `animal_store` does not appear to be straight forward. You have to build whole Hash structure and Food objects... don't bother the test author with the details, instead pass the animals as a [transient attribute](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes) and do the work in the factory.

```
factory :animal_store do
  # Give them sensible defaults.
  transient do
    animals { create_list(:animal, num_target_animals) }
    num_animals { 3 }
    foods { create_list(:food, num_foods) }
    num_foods { 3 }
  end

  timestamp { DateTime.now }

  # targets is complex enough that it benefits from its own factory.
  # Pass the supplied animals and foods through.
  targets factory: :animal_store_targets, animals: animals, foods: foods
end

factory :animal_store_targets, class: Hash do
  transient do
    animals { create_list(:animal, num_target_animals) }
    num_animals { 3 }
    foods { create_list(:food, num_foods) }
    num_foods { 3 }
  end

  targets do
    # I'll leave building the targets Hash from animals and foods to you.
  end

  # Cheap trick to make a Hash with symbol keys.
  initialize_with do
    attributes
  end
end
```